# flutter: migrate to null safety an old project

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have this libraries in my project:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  after_layout: ^1.1.0
  alt_sms_autofill: ^1.0.0
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.24
  avatar_glow: ^2.0.2
  barcode_scan2: ^4.1.4
  camera: ^0.9.2+2
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  catcher: ^0.6.8
  charts_flutter: ^0.11.0
  contacts_service: ^0.6.3
  crypto: ^3.0.1
  cryptography: ^2.0.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  device_info: ^2.0.3
  dio: ^4.0.1
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+1
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  file_picker: ^4.2.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.9
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.1.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0
  geolocator: ^7.7.1
  get_it: ^7.1.3
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.7.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+1
  installed_apps: ^1.2.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  json_annotation: ^4.0.1
  local_auth: ^1.1.7
  logger: ^1.1.0
  mask_text_input_formatter: ^2.0.0
  otp: ^3.0.1
  overlay_support: ^1.2.1
  package_info_plus: ^1.3.0
  page_view_indicators: ^2.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.4
  permission_handler: ^8.1.6
  persian: ^1.1.1
  persian_datetime_picker:
    path: packages/persian_datetime_picker
  persian_number_utility: ^1.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  quick_actions: ^0.6.0+6
  retrofit: ^2.1.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.2
  screenshot: ^1.2.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
  timezone: ^0.8.0
  universal_html: ^2.0.8
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0
  uuid: ^3.0.5
  video_player: ^2.2.3
  visibility_detector: ^0.2.2
  wc_flutter_share: ^0.4.0
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.13

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.1.2
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator: ^1.1.1
  http_mock_adapter: ^0.3.2
  json_serializable: ^4.1.4
  mockito: ^5.0.15
  retrofit_generator: ^2.0.1
```

I run this command and It's result:

```
$ flutter pub upgrade --null-safety
Resolving dependencies...
  _fe_analyzer_shared 22.0.0 (30.0.0 available)
  after_layout 1.1.0
  alt_sms_autofill 1.0.0
  analyzer 1.7.1 (2.7.0 available)
  another_flushbar 1.10.24
  args 2.3.0
  asn1lib 1.0.2
  async 2.5.0 (2.8.2 available)
  avatar_glow 2.0.2
  barcode_scan2 4.1.4
  base32 2.1.1
  boolean_selector 2.1.0
  build 2.1.0 (2.1.1 available)
  build_config 1.0.0
  build_daemon 3.0.0 (3.0.1 available)
  build_resolvers 2.0.4
  build_runner 2.1.2 (2.1.4 available)
  build_runner_core 7.1.0 (7.2.2 available)
  built_collection 5.1.1
  built_value 8.1.3
  camera 0.9.2+2 (0.9.4+3 available)
  camera_platform_interface 2.1.1
  carousel_slider 4.0.0
  catcher 0.6.8
  characters 1.1.0 (1.2.0 available)
  charcode 1.2.0 (1.3.1 available)
  charts_common 0.11.0 (0.12.0 available)
  charts_flutter 0.11.0
  checked_yaml 2.0.1
  cli_util 0.3.5
  clock 1.1.0
  code_builder 4.1.0
  collection 1.15.0
  contacts_service 0.6.3
  convert 3.0.1
  cross_file 0.3.2
  crypto 3.0.1
  cryptography 2.0.2
  csslib 0.17.1
  cupertino_icons 1.0.3
  dart_style 2.1.1 (2.2.0 available)
  device_info 2.0.3
  device_info_platform_interface 2.0.1
  device_info_plus 2.2.0 (3.1.0 available)
  device_info_plus_linux 2.1.0
  device_info_plus_macos 2.2.0
  device_info_plus_platform_interface 2.2.0
  device_info_plus_web 2.1.0
  device_info_plus_windows 2.1.0
  dio 4.0.1
  dio_http 5.0.4
  dots_indicator 2.0.0
  dotted_border 2.0.0+1
  encrypt 5.0.1
  fake_async 1.2.0
  ffi 1.1.2
  file 6.1.2
  file_picker 4.2.0
  firebase_core 1.8.0
  firebase_core_platform_interface 4.0.1
  firebase_core_web 1.1.0
  firebase_messaging 10.0.9
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface 3.0.7
  firebase_messaging_web 2.0.7
  fixnum 1.0.0
  flutter 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  flutter_inappwebview 5.3.2
  flutter_keyboard_visibility 5.1.0
  flutter_keyboard_visibility_platform_interface 2.0.0
  flutter_keyboard_visibility_web 2.0.0
  flutter_localizations 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  flutter_mailer 2.0.0
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.4
  flutter_rating_bar 4.0.0
  flutter_slidable 0.6.0
  flutter_svg 0.23.0+1
  flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 from sdk flutter
  fluttertoast 8.0.8
  font_awesome_flutter 9.2.0
  frontend_server_client 2.1.2
  geolocator 7.7.1
  geolocator_android 2.1.0
  geolocator_apple 1.2.2
  geolocator_platform_interface 2.3.6
  geolocator_web 2.0.6
  get_it 7.1.3 (7.2.0 available)
  glob 2.0.1 (2.0.2 available)
  graphs 2.1.0
  hive 2.0.4
  hive_flutter 1.1.0
  hive_generator 1.1.1
  html 0.15.0
  http 0.13.3 (0.13.4 available)
  http_mock_adapter 0.3.2
  http_multi_server 3.0.1
  http_parser 4.0.0
  image_cropper 1.4.1
  image_gallery_saver 1.7.1
  image_picker 0.8.4+1 (0.8.4+4 available)
  image_picker_for_web 2.1.4
  image_picker_platform_interface 2.4.1
  installed_apps 1.2.0
  intl 0.17.0
  introduction_screen 2.1.0
  io 1.0.3
  js 0.6.3
  json_annotation 4.0.1 (4.3.0 available)
  json_serializable 4.1.4 (6.0.1 available)
  local_auth 1.1.7 (1.1.8 available)
  logger 1.1.0
  logging 1.0.2
  mailer 5.0.2
  mask_text_input_formatter 2.0.0
  matcher 0.12.10 (0.12.11 available)
  meta 1.3.0 (1.7.0 available)
  mime 1.0.1
  mockito 5.0.15 (5.0.16 available)
  nested 1.0.0
  otp 3.0.1
  overlay_support 1.2.1
  package_config 2.0.2
  package_info_plus 1.3.0
  package_info_plus_linux 1.0.3
  package_info_plus_macos 1.3.0
  package_info_plus_platform_interface 1.0.2
  package_info_plus_web 1.0.4
  package_info_plus_windows 1.0.4
  page_view_indicators 2.0.0
  path 1.8.0
  path_drawing 0.5.1+1
  path_parsing 0.2.1
  path_provider 2.0.4 (2.0.6 available)
  path_provider_linux 2.1.0
  path_provider_macos 2.0.2
  path_provider_platform_interface 2.0.1
  path_provider_windows 2.0.3
  pedantic 1.11.1 (discontinued replaced by lints)
  permission_handler 8.1.6 (8.2.5 available)
  permission_handler_platform_interface 3.6.1 (3.7.0 available)
  persian 1.1.1
  persian_datetime_picker 2.0.0 from path packages/persian_datetime_picker
  persian_number_utility 1.1.0
  petitparser 4.1.0 (4.4.0 available)
  platform 3.0.2
  plugin_platform_interface 2.0.2
  pointycastle 3.3.5
  pool 1.5.0
  process 4.2.3 (4.2.4 available)
  protobuf 2.0.0
  provider 6.0.1
  pub_semver 2.1.0
  pubspec_parse 1.0.0 (1.1.0 available)
  quick_actions 0.6.0+6 (0.6.0+7 available)
  quick_actions_platform_interface 1.0.0
  quiver 3.0.1+1
  retrofit 2.1.0
  retrofit_generator 2.0.1 (2.1.0+1 available)
  rxdart 0.27.2
  screenshot 1.2.3
  sentry 5.1.0 (6.0.1 available)
  shamsi_date 0.16.0
  shared_preferences 2.0.7 (2.0.8 available)
  shared_preferences_linux 2.0.2
  shared_preferences_macos 2.0.2
  shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.0.0
  shared_preferences_web 2.0.2
  shared_preferences_windows 2.0.2
  shelf 1.2.0
  shelf_web_socket 1.0.1
  sky_engine 0.0.99 from sdk flutter
  source_gen 1.0.3 (1.1.1 available)
  source_helper 1.3.0
  source_span 1.8.0 (1.8.1 available)
  sqflite 2.0.0+4
  sqflite_common 2.0.1+1
  stack_trace 1.10.0
  stream_channel 2.1.0
  stream_transform 2.0.0
  string_scanner 1.1.0
  synchronized 3.0.0
  term_glyph 1.2.0
  test_api 0.2.19 (0.4.7 available)
  timezone 0.8.0
  timing 1.0.0
  tuple 2.0.0
  typed_data 1.3.0
  universal_html 2.0.8
  universal_io 2.0.4
  url_launcher 6.0.10 (6.0.12 available)
  url_launcher_linux 2.0.2
  url_launcher_macos 2.0.2
  url_launcher_platform_interface 2.0.4
  url_launcher_web 2.0.4
  url_launcher_windows 2.0.2
  url_strategy 0.2.0
  uuid 3.0.5
  vector_math 2.1.0 (2.1.1 available)
  video_player 2.2.3 (2.2.6 available)
  video_player_platform_interface 4.2.0
  video_player_web 2.0.4
  visibility_detector 0.2.2
  watcher 1.0.0 (1.0.1 available)
  wc_flutter_share 0.4.0
  web_socket_channel 2.1.0
  webview_flutter 2.0.13 (2.1.2 available)
  win32 2.0.5 (2.2.10 available)
  xdg_directories 0.2.0
  xml 5.1.2 (5.3.1 available)
  yaml 3.1.0
No dependencies changed.
43 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

No changes to pubspec.yaml!
```

Why I  cant update my libs, I want to migrate my old project to null safety?

Comment: Did you try `flutter pub outdated`?

Comment: `packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints` That tells you right there. You have packages that have dependency issues. It can be a pain to weed these out. IDEs can sometimes help. VS Code shows some of the error details in the "OUTPUT" terminal window. ‍♂️

Comment: Yes, just shows that libraries must be updated @NirmalCode

Comment: My suggestion is to upgrade lib versions manually so that you know which are upgraded. Also, there can be breaking changes, dependency changes.

Comment: I do that, but I got error to my model that generated by json serilaizer

Comment: If a package has null-safety version, I recommend to upgrade to it. However, you have to be careful of packages that share dependencies. You have to find packages whose versions can be as up to date as possible while maintaining compatibility with each other.

Comment: I manually updated but I got this error `Because url_launcher 6.0.12 requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0 and no versions of url_launcher match >6.0.12 <7.0.0, url_launcher ^6.0.12 is forbidden.` @daddygames

Comment: Your pubspec has `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"` which does not meet the requirements of the version of url_launcher you are trying to use. You would need to update to `sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"` However, this will require all packages have null-safety. Therefore you may need to downgrade the version of url_launcher you use.

Answer (score 0):

First backup your project for safety.

Try this,

```
flutter clean
```

Now delete `pubspec.lock` file.

Now delete all the versions from `pubspec.yaml`.

Leaving version number empty, let flutter decide which to use.

Upgrade SDK version,

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```

Now run,

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: My project is not null safety

Comment: Which SDK I have to use? 2.5.2

Comment: Then this will not help. Also, you need to upgrade all the packages manually. Because most of the packages now use null-safety.

Comment: Dark SDK version less than 2.12.0

Comment: I am using 2.0.6 and I got this error ```Because ip_flutter requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because ip_flutter requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)```

Comment: Goto the versions tab of that package on `pub.dev`. Check the min SDK and choose the latest that matches your version

Comment: This is what I was trying to say. You will need to balance the sdk version with the requirements of the packages you use. You may not be able to use all the latest packages.